# Special characters in cue files: shnsplit breaks

Tags: bash, flac

I am using the following one-liner to split my flac file with cue sheet into several flac files:

```
shntool split -f "Album.cue" -o flac -t '%n - %p - %t' "Album.flac"
```

Problem is: when the title in the cue sheet contains "ç" or "?" the corresponding splitted file seems corrupt, and I cannot listen to it. Of course if I remove the title altogether:

```
-t '%n - %p'
```

Files are created without any error.

So, how do I handle those special characters n the cue sheet (that arose with titles, but it could also impact performer's name")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what solved the problem for me was first to convert the .cue file to UTF-8 encoding using:

```
conv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8//TRANSLIT cuefile.cue -o reencoded_cuefile.cue
```